# What is the max length of nodejs execFile callback params "stdout"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I use child_process to excute yslow.js by phantomjs. 
Example(CLI):

```
 phantomjs yslow.js --info all --format json url
```

We can get the analytic data that yslow.js return to me after analyzing.

But sometimes the data yslow.js return to me can not be a complete json file. Is seem the callback params "stdout" can not be too a large length data. I guess If the data is too large can infect the params stdout...

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is solved.
child_process supports maxbuffer option.
We can do like this:

```
child_process.execFile(file, [args], {maxBuffer: 1024 * 102400 }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if(stderr){
            console.log(stderr);
        }else {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can send data by chunks then use `spawn` instead of `exec`. Otherwise you can send data via temporary file. Also you can use WebSockets to create channel between node and phantom.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in the promise

```
{maxBuffer: 1024 * 102400 }
```

Example :

```
restore.Restore().then({ maxBuffer: 1024 * 102400 }, function (result) {});
```